# PostgresSQL Error - Issue with Real DataType

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

The following is the error I get for trying to insert a number for a column with the data type of real for a Postgres DB:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type real: "40960.00"
CONTEXT:  COPY table_of_interest, line 1, column col_1: "40960.00"
```

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to Postgres, I have much more experience with Oracle, MySQL, and Microsoft SQL Server. I can't figure out why this does not insert? In the CSV it is trying to insert from, the column is just a basic number column. That number does not contain the double quotes around it.

I am also getting a following error when trying to insert via python:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This is the first row I want to insert, as an example (error above still remains):

```
(Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-10-03 00:00:00'),
 'APP-552498',
 'Company Name Lawyer',
 'Funded',
 36500,
 1095.0,
 1.35,
 49275.0,
 15509.0,
 251.0,
 'Daily',
 1825.0,
 196.31,
 78,
 0.0,
 'Law Offices',
 NaT,
 '',
 'CO',
 8.4,
 'Company Name',
 0.7647,
 38003.68,
 7154.34,
 'West',
 33766.0,
 'N')
```

I put the first two columns as type date, every column with a number as real, and the strings as character varying. Of course, the column that has NaT is also a date (and accordingly a datetime in python).

The following is the python code:

```
df_vals = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
c.execute("""INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (%s)""", df_vals[0])
c.executemany("""INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (%s)""", df_vals)
```

where c is an already created cursor from conn.cursor()

Comment: what is the result of ```SELECT '40960.00'::REAL;``` ? ... if the same error then your DB is somehow configured to use comma as a standart decimal separator for numerics input/output .. then try reading about ```LC_NUMERIC```.

Comment: This gives me float4 real 40960

Comment: What's extremely strange is I truncated the table, re-inserted after downloading to a separate csv file, and it worked. This could be a psycopg2 problem.

Comment: You will need to show the  exact psycopg2 code you are using. The error indicates that there is a mismatch between the values being passed in and the parameters in your code.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I just added in the python code.